# How to show images using Firebase Push Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to broadcast to all users when a blog is posted.
Each blog has an image or video.

Broadcasting with normal text is not a problem, but I should show posted image or video in Android notification.

I have found the following link: http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/

However I still strugle on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

From official [Firebase FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm):

**Message Type**
Notifications up to 2kb
Data messages up to 4kb

So instead of trying to push image inside message, your application should do differently (for example using webview with image URL).